# SQL table partition on same criteria as clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does it make sense to partition a table on the same criteria as the clustered index? For example, I have a table with a timestamp field. this timestamp is what the clustered index is based on and I want to partition the table by that timestamp into years.

Does it make sense to do that or should I change the clustered index to some other criteria (essentially like having two clustered indexes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real problem with partitioning on the clustered index.

It is common for an incrementing clustered index to be used, such that new data only go into the last partition.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a clustered index partitioned in one way and the table partitioned another way. This is simply because the clustered index **is** the table. If you create a table (a heap) on partition scheme `A` and then you build a clustered index on it on a partition scheme `B` then in the end you will have a table on partition scheme `B`. You simply cannot have both a table (a heap) *and* a clustered index. They are mutually exclusive.

A legitimate question is whether you can have non-clustered index on different partitions than the clustered index. Technically yes, you can, but this creates so called 'unaligned indexes', which are problematic from two points of view:

- they prevent partition switch operations, see [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx)
- they cause performance problems see [Memory Limitations and Partitioned Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187526.aspx)

Comment: as I remember you can partition on a CL that has multiple columns and then choose any of those columns as the partition key though. That is kind of CL one way, partition another - but not truely independant.

Comment: @Andrew: right, the partitioning key can be any of the columns that compose the clustered index key: `When partitioning a clustered index, the clustering key must contain the partitioning column. When partitioning a nonunique clustered index, and the partitioning column is not explicitly specified in the clustering key, SQL Server adds the partitioning column by default to the list of clustered index keys. If the clustered index is unique, you must explicitly specify that the clustered index key contain the partitioning column.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187526.aspx